# WAMP não armazena

Tags: php, wamp

Olá, não está dando erro nenhum, porém o `WAMP` não salva as informações.

Código do `cadastro_db.php`:

```
<?
include("conection.php");

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$idade = $_POST['idade'];
$cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuarios(nome, email, idade, cidade, login, senha, foto) value('$nome',                     '$email', '$idade', '$cidade', '$login', '$senha', '$foto')");
header("Location: index.php");  

?>
```

Codigo do `conection.php`:

```
<?
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db($db, "login_senha");
?>
```

Grato desde já.

Comment: Wamp não é o problema, Wamp significa Windows, Apache, Mysql, Php. O problema foi no uso da API mysqli misturada com a API mysql. Wamp não poderia falhar neste sentido, já que ele é um conjunto de softwares, o que no máximo poderia falhar é um deles separadas :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua conexão está utilizando funções do `mysqli_*`, e em sua consulta você usa `mysql_*`. O correto é você adaptar tudo para o MySQLi. Mas não pense em momento nenhum [mudar para o MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)! E um detalhe, nessa linha:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
```

Você **deve** renomear `$db` para algo que lembre conexão, afinal, `$db` não guarda um banco de dados, e sim uma conexão MySQLi.

Reescrevendo seu código, fica assim:

### connection.php

```
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysqli_select_db($con, "login_senha");
?>
```

### cadastro_db.php

```
<?php
  include("conection.php");

  $nome = $_POST['nome'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $idade = $_POST['idade'];
  $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
  $login = $_POST['login'];
  $senha = $_POST['senha'];

  $sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO usuarios(nome, email, idade, cidade, login, senha, foto) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$idade', '$cidade', '$login', '$senha', '$foto')");
  mysqli_close($con); // Fecha a conexão antes de redirecionar
  header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Preste atenção para as linhas que eu mudei, renomeei a variável no `connection.php` e alterei o método `mysql_query` para `mysqli_query`. Perceba que eu também corrigi um erro na sua SQL, você escreveu `value`, o correto é `VALUES`.

Para mais informações, leia:

- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php